# FIAPARCH Model in r

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to implement a Fiaparch model in r.
Most people use Ox, but I found this command that simulates Ox:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fGarch/versions/260.72/topics/GarchOxInterface

It is part of the fGARCH package, which I installed.
However, the command is not recognized when I run it.

So, I was wondering if I set it up wrong, or whether there is an additional package I should download, or if I should have Ox in my computer in order to run this command?

```
install.packages("fGarch")
library(fGarch)

garchOxFit(formula = ~arma(2,1)+fiaparch(1,1), data=logreturns, 
           cond.dist = c("gaussian", "t", "ged", "skewed-t"),
           include.mean = TRUE, trace = TRUE, control = list(), title = NULL,
           description = NULL)
```

Output:

> Error in garchOxFit(formula = ~arma(2, 1) + fiaparch(1, 1), data =
>   logreturns,  :    could not find function "garchOxFit"

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but the github function has commands such as:

  command = "C:\\Ox\\bin\\oxl.exe C:\\Ox\\lib\\GarchOxModelling.ox"

which are not recognized. Should I have Ox on my pc?

Comment: I did not try it. It costs 250 pounds for one academic license. I was looking for a cheaper (free) alternative.